# Adding a description to an acronym

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I'm using a glossary and also some acronyms, but some of the acronyms are complicated so I want to have a description for them in the glossary.

Something like this:

```
\newacronym{gwa}{GWA}{Gateway Administrator} % desc= A guy who has fun with IT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which package you are using for glossaries creation.

In you case, you are most probably using glossaries package. I suggest you use following:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\setacronymstyle{long-short-desc}

\newacronym
[description={A guy who has fun with IT}]
{gwa}{GWA}{Gateway Administrator}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\printglossaries

\gls{gwa}.

\end{document}
```

You have to use glossary style, that supports descrption field in acronym definition, and also define the description as optional argument of \newacronym command. Arara is compilation automation tool, that I am using for my convenience. If you are compiling with makeglossaries separately, it works too.

The way of solving you question might differ depending on which package you are using for glossaries creation. Next time, please, provide and MWE suitable to work with.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know about packages. It works, thank you very much!